# Gamma function in $C^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

How can I show that for $x>0$, the Gamma function is at least $C^{2}$? The Gamma function is defined as $$\displaystyle \int^\infty_0 e^{-t}t^{x-1}\ dt$$ For which $x$ is the integrand integrable?

Comment: You should go for $C^1$ first. Try to write up the definition of the derivative, and see if you can move the limit operation inside the integral. Or did you try that already?

Comment: could u plz more explain it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint for doing the first part ($C^1$): 
$$\frac{\Gamma(x+h)-\Gamma(x)}{h}
 =\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\frac{t^{x+h-1}-t^{x-1}}{h}\,dt
 =\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x+\theta h-1}\ln t\,dt$$
where the first part is just the definition of the derivative, and I used the mean value theorem for the function $x\mapsto t^x$ in the second equality. Here $0<\theta<1$ is some function of $t$, $x$, and $h$. Now try to see what happens when you let $h\to0$. (To use the tools of Lebesgue theory, you need to replace $h$ by $h_n$, where the sequence $(h_n)$ converges to zero.)

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to do in the complex plane.  If a sequence of analytic functions on a domain $D$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $D$, then the limit is analytic.

Comment: Indeed, but the question is tagged with measure-theory, so we (or rather the OP) will probably have to assume a different toolkit.